# Turn one column into multiple columns by key words

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I split a column into more columns base on the specific words? For example, I have table **A** and I want to split col wherever the words "AND, OR, PLUS" appears, so that I get table **B** as the result.

A

| ID | col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | THE BIG APPLE AND ORANGE OR PEAR |
| 2 | BANNANA EATS GRAPE OR BLUEBERRY |
| 3 | THE BEST FRUIT IS WATERMELON |
| 4 | FRUITS OR CANDY ARE THE BEST OR WATER |
| 5 | APPLE STRAWBERRY AND PLUM PLUS SUGAR OR PEACH |
| 6 | MELON IN MY BELLY |

B

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | THE BIG APPLE | ORANGE | PEAR |  |
| 2 | BANNANA EATS GRAPE | BLUEBERRY |  |  |
| 3 | THE BEST FRUIT IS WATERMELON |  |  |  |
| 4 | FRUITS | CANDY ARE THE BEST | WATER |  |
| 5 | APPLE STRAWBERRY | PLUM | SUGAR | PEACH |
| 6 | MELON IN MY BELLY |  |  |  |

Comment: When are you going to accept an answer to your questions? You've asked several questions this week, have been provided good answers, yet you haven't accepted any yet.

Comment: My apologies, I am still learning how this platform works. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: No problem, glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         idx,
         match
  FROM   table_name
         CROSS APPLY (
           SELECT LEVEL AS idx,
                  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                    col,
                    '(.+?)(\s+(AND|OR|PLUS)\s+|$)',
                    1,
                    LEVEL,
                    'i',
                    1
                  ) AS match
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(
                    col,
                    '(.+?)(\s+(AND|OR|PLUS)\s+|$)',
                    1,
                    'i'
                  )
         )
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(match)
  FOR idx IN (1 AS col1, 2 AS col2, 3 AS col3, 4 AS col4)
);
```

*Note: SQL statements **MUST** have a fixed number of output columns so you cannot dynamically set the number of columns with a static SQL statement. It would possibly be better to just use the inner query (without the outer wrapper which performs the `PIVOT`) and output the values as rows rather than columns and then if you want to transpose to columns then do it in whatever front-end you are using to access the database.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, col) AS
SELECT 1, 'THE BIG APPLE AND ORANGE OR PEAR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'BANNANA EATS GRAPE OR BLUEBERRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'THE BEST FRUIT IS WATERMELON' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'FRUITS OR CANDY ARE THE BEST OR WATER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'APPLE STRAWBERRY AND PLUM PLUS SUGAR OR PEACH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'MELON IN MY BELLY' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | THE BIG APPLE | ORANGE | PEAR | *null* |
> | 2 | BANNANA EATS GRAPE | BLUEBERRY | *null* | *null* |
> | 3 | THE BEST FRUIT IS WATERMELON | *null* | *null* | *null* |
> | 4 | FRUITS | CANDY ARE THE BEST | WATER | *null* |
> | 5 | APPLE STRAWBERRY | PLUM | SUGAR | PEACH |
> | 6 | MELON IN MY BELLY | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7b55d50647cd605507fdd6196ab55dc5)*